# python's lists ,tuples and for loop

Tags: python

i have a list :

```
a=[1, 2, 3, 300] # this is IDs of workers
```

And a list of tuples :

```
f=[(1, 1, 1), (1, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (1, 500, 600)]
```

For every element in a ( a[i]) it has a related element (tuple) in f ( f[i) ) . So what i need is to sum the elements in f[i] for every a[i] till certain indices according to user . For example if user want the summation to end till certain index say 2 , the output will then be for ID 1=a[0]  --> sum will be 2 (f[0]=1 +f[1]=1 ) , for ID 2=a[2] --> the summation is 1 [f[0]=0+f[1]=1] and so on till a[3]
here is my code :

```
str1=int(input('enter the index[enter -->1/2/3]'))
a=[1, 2, 3, 300]
f=[(1, 1, 1), (1, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (1, 500, 600)]
length=len(a)
temp=0 #sum
for i in range(0,length):
    y=a[i]
    att_2=f[i]
    print("{} {}".format("The worker ID is ", y))
    for z in range(0,(str1)):
        temp=temp+att_2[i]
        print(temp) # tracing the sum
```

I getting a error plus wrong result for some a[i] :

```
enter the index[enter -->1/2/3]2
 temp=temp+att_2[i]
IndexError: tuple index out of range
The Student ID is  1
1
2
The Student ID is  2
2
2
The Student ID is  3
2
2
The Student ID is  300

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I am trying to fix these errors , but i cannot find its reasons. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your Error is because you have mixed up the variable `i` and the variable `z`.

Your code loops through the tuple using variable `i` and that will result in an error as the maximum value `i` will take is calculated for another set of instructions.

A switch of variables on line 11 will fix your problems

*Original:*

```
str1=int(input('enter the index[enter -->1/2/3]'))
a=[1, 2, 3, 300]
f=[(1, 1, 1), (1, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (1, 500, 600)]
length=len(a)
temp=0 #sum
for i in range(0,length):
    y=a[i]
    att_2=f[i]
    print("{} {}".format("The worker ID is ", y))
    for z in range(0,(str1)):
        temp=temp+att_2[i]
        print(temp) # tracing the sum
```

*New:*

```
str1=int(input('enter the index[enter -->1/2/3]'))
a=[1, 2, 3, 300]
f=[(1, 1, 1), (1, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (1, 500, 600)]
length=len(a)
temp=0 #sum
for i in range(0,length):
    y=a[i]
    att_2=f[i]
    print("{} {}".format("The worker ID is ", y))
    for z in range(0,(str1)):
        temp=temp+att_2[z]
        print(temp) # tracing the sum
```